# What is a metric to measure the similarity of any two sets

Tags: machine-learning, set, similarity, metrics, precision-recall

I seek a function that will assign a real number to any two sets based on their elements alone.  I need it to be sensitive to the extent of the intersection of the sets but to penalize if the sets have extraneous items.  In other words I want to count both recall and precision in the same metric.

Comment: Does this work? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Comment: Maybe something like `crc32(json.stringify(data))`

Comment: Also this question may be better asked on:   
Cross Validated or  Artificial Intelligence which are sister sites to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are probably right about the other sister site.  However, @Martin Thoma gave me the perfect answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index):

```
J(A, B) := |A ∩ B| / |A ∪ B|
```

Hence it counts how many elements both sets have in common and divides it by the number of unique elements.

J(A, B) is at maximum 1 if both sets are identical. The minimum is zero, if they don't share any element. You might want to assign a number for the case that both sets are empty.

Comment: That is great.  I checked it out and that will do the trick.  Thanks much

Comment: @LewisEigen If it solved your problem, you should accept my answer. If you think my answer was written in a good way, you should upvote it.

Comment: I'm new to this site and didn't know about "upvoting" but I have now clicked the check so it turned green and clicked the up arrow, albeit the numeral did not change.  It said something about not counting votes without 15 reputation points.  Have I upvoted it?  I really do appreciate the answer, it was perfect for me.